# SQlDataAdapter connection has not been initialized

Tags: vb.net

Maybe simple question, but cannot figure out. After call GetRodzaje method which will fill my grid, there is also button which could be clicked to save changes back to database unfortunetly if i click it my second method GetRodzajeMakeChanges giving me an error that like it would lost connection to database, but i am opening the connection there.

```
connection has not been initialized
```

Why is that happen as i am opening the connection? Can you support here?:

This is my code:

```
Imports System.Configuration
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Windows.Forms
Imports DataAccessLayer

Public Class ProjektDAO

    Private GetRodzajeDataSet As New DataSet
    Private GetRodzajeDataAdapter As SqlDataAdapter
    Private MyConnection As SqlConnection

    Private strcon = New AppSettingsReader().GetValue("ConnectionString", GetType(System.String)).ToString()

    Public Function GetRodzaje() As DataSet

        Using MyConnection = New SqlConnection(strcon)
            Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tbProjekt", MyConnection)
            MyConnection.Open()
            GetRodzajeDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
            GetRodzajeDataAdapter.Fill(GetRodzajeDataSet, "trial1")
        End Using

        Return GetRodzajeDataSet

    End Function


    Public Sub GetRodzajeMakeChanges()
        If Not GetRodzajeDataSet.HasChanges Then
            MessageBox.Show("Nie ma zmian do zapisania", "Informacja", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
        Else

            Dim cmdbuilder As New SqlCommandBuilder(GetRodzajeDataAdapter)
            Dim i As Integer
            Try
                Using MyConnection = New SqlConnection(strcon)
                    MyConnection.Open()
                    i = GetRodzajeDataAdapter.Update(GetRodzajeDataSet, "trial1")
                End Using

                MsgBox("Zaktualizowano " & i & " rekordów")
            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox(ex.Message)
            End Try
        End If

    End Sub


    Public Function GetRodzajeCheckChanges() As Boolean
        Dim result As Boolean = False
        If GetRodzajeDataSet.HasChanges Then
            result = True
        End If
        Return result
    End Function



End Class
```

This one is working but ... i below code is not closing connection anywhere, not use using clause on conenction so i assume its not correct, please help me out what should i do? Use below code or first with some fix?:

```
Imports System.Configuration
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Windows.Forms
Imports DataAccessLayer

Public Class ProjektDAO

    Private GetRodzajeDataSet As New DataSet
    Private GetRodzajeDataAdapter As SqlDataAdapter

    Private strcon = New AppSettingsReader().GetValue("ConnectionString", GetType(System.String)).ToString()

    Public Function GetProjects() As DataSet
        Dim con As New SqlConnection(strcon)
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tbProjekt", con)
        con.Open()
        GetRodzajeDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
            GetRodzajeDataAdapter.Fill(GetRodzajeDataSet, "trial1")


        Return GetRodzajeDataSet

    End Function


    Public Sub GetProjectMakeChanges()
        If Not GetRodzajeDataSet.HasChanges Then
            MessageBox.Show("Nie ma zmian do zapisania", "Informacja", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
        Else

            Dim cmdbuilder As New SqlCommandBuilder(GetRodzajeDataAdapter)
            Dim i As Integer
            Try


                i = GetRodzajeDataAdapter.Update(GetRodzajeDataSet, "trial1")


                MsgBox("Zaktualizowano " & i & " rekordów")
            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox(ex.Message)
            End Try
        End If

    End Sub


    Public Function GetProjectCheckChanges() As Boolean
        Dim result As Boolean = False
        If GetRodzajeDataSet.HasChanges Then
            result = True
        End If
        Return result
    End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some fields (GetRodzajeDataAdapter, MyConnection) on class level that should be moved to class level in order to have a consistent lifetime. Right now, your code never uses the `MyConnection` field on class level, but always creates a new variable in method scope. I'd change the code as follows:

```
' ...
Public Class ProjektDAO

    Private GetRodzajeDataSet As New DataSet
    ' Remove this:  Private GetRodzajeDataAdapter As SqlDataAdapter
    ' Remove this: Private MyConnection As SqlConnection

    Private strcon = New AppSettingsReader().GetValue("ConnectionString", GetType(System.String)).ToString()

    Public Function GetRodzaje() As DataSet

        Using MyConnection = New SqlConnection(strcon)
            Using cmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tbProjekt", MyConnection)
                MyConnection.Open()
                ' Create a data adapter in the method and throw it away afterwards
                Using GetRodzajeDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
                    GetRodzajeDataAdapter.Fill(GetRodzajeDataSet, "trial1")
                End Using
            End Using
        End Using

        Return GetRodzajeDataSet

    End Function


    Public Sub GetRodzajeMakeChanges()
        If Not GetRodzajeDataSet.HasChanges Then
            MessageBox.Show("Nie ma zmian do zapisania", "Informacja", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
        Else

            Dim i As Integer
            Try
                Using MyConnection = New SqlConnection(strcon)
                    Using cmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tbProjekt", MyConnection)
                        MyConnection.Open()
                        ' Create a data adapter in the method and throw it away afterwards
                        Using GetRodzajeDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
                            Dim cmdbuilder As New SqlCommandBuilder(GetRodzajeDataAdapter)
                            i = GetRodzajeDataAdapter.Update(GetRodzajeDataSet, "trial1")
                        End Using
                    End Using
                End Using

                MsgBox("Zaktualizowano " & i & " rekordów")
            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox(ex.Message)
            End Try
        End If

    End Sub
    ' ...
End Class
```

This way, the connection and the data adapter is always created in the method. In addition, I've moved the command builder inside the Using block for the data adapter in the second method so that the commands for Insert, Update and Delete are generated.

Comment: so simply saying i have to always create sqldataadapter and sqlcommandbuilder e.g if i would add some additional new method to this class correct?

Comment: @StackUser: you don't have to, but it is easier because you don't have to assert that the state stays valid over the lifetime of the instance. In order to reduce the amount of code that you have to write in all these methods, you can move the repeated parts into a separate method and reuse this method.

Comment: ok, i think ill go your way to always create adapter, command, connection open/close to separate methods. In case connection think its good because we open/close only when we need it right and not global variable and check states - am i right regarding conenction? Or its better to manipualte one global connection variable what do you think?